# How to add contact text field to drupal content type

Tags: emails

I am trying to create a business directory. I have created a content type with the following fields:

[image]

I would like to add another field for public users to be able to type a message and send to the business owner. When I add content, I like to enter the email address of the business owner. When people type a message and send, it should send an email to the business owner with a predefined email subject. Users should not see the subject field. How can I achieve it?

Comment: You should really use something like Webform for this. Alternatively, if I were you I would implement a custom form with a custom module, so I could keep the entity ID in the URL, which I would retrieve the email to send to on form submit.

Comment: If I use webform, how can I specify the business owner's email address? I will add webform content one by one. As I am adding content, I am not sure how I would enter business owner's email address so people can type message and send to business owners email.